# Relative homologies involving homotopic subspaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is the following correct?  If not, how can it be modified so as to be correct (e.g., does $Y$ need to contain $A$)?  (here $Y \simeq$ means "$Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.")

If $Y \subset X$ and $Y \simeq X$, then $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(Y,A)$.

References appreciated!

Comment: If $Y$ doesn't contain $A$ then what does $H_n(Y,A)$ mean?

Comment: @AreaMan That's what I wanted to know!  (Maybe the person who told me this statement was true intended $A \subset Y$ to be implied?)

Comment: Also, what does $Y \simeq X$ mean?

Comment: @LeeMosher $Y \simeq X$ means "$Y$ is homotopic to $X$."  Maybe I should add that...

Comment: "Homotopy" is a relation between functions, not between spaces, so saying "$Y$ is homotopic to $X$" does not make sense. There is a closely related equivalence relation between spaces known as "homotopy equivalence", so it might make sense to say "$Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$". In the special case of a subspace $Y \subset X$, there is a stronger relation where one says "the injection $Y \subset X$ is a homotopy equivalence", and a still stronger relation where one says "$Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$". Perhaps you mean one of those?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, I meant homotopy equivalent...  I think my teacher sometimes just says "homotopic" though, and I guess she is not the only one who does (see Definition 3 at [these lecture notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/Week%201%20Term%202.pdf) ).